# Facebook Graph API - Getting Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook graph API to get all the comments (mine and others) on my Facebook posts.

Currently I'm testing the api using Graph API Explorer & so far I'm getting only my comments.

I want to know did they change their policy or is there a way to get all the comments?

P.S: I didn't write any code so far.
But I followed the link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started
to use the graph API explorer and this is what I'm getting:

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZHn3.png)

In the **"Tools"** you will find the tool. And as you can see you will get the list of the comments. I'm just showing one of my comments (testingggg) as an example.

Unfortunately, the API doesn't give me the others' comments.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, although you have outlined your predicament, it is still difficult to help out without the aid of code samples. Seeing what you have done so far is important in being able to provide a solution

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited my request by including a capture and a link of what I'm doing.

Answer (score -1):

according to the document this is the way to get all the comment [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/object/comments)